# Custom nameserver/search path for Ubuntu in Vmware?

Tags: networking, ubuntu-10.04, vmware-workstation

in my Ubuntu VMWare guest I'm using bridged network to gain access to my lan. The network setup per see works, but the nameserver is set to my router (and works) although I'm running dnsmasq on another server  to handle internal names (and forward to the router).

Where can I customize the network so I've my own `nameserver` and `search` path in `/etc/resolv.conf` ?

My `/etc/network/interfaces` looks like

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
#iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

I don't remember touching it, basic setup worked out of the box.

I *think* the default setup is using `dhcp`? At least `dhclient` is running.

My `/etc/resolv.conf` is

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 192.168.1.1
```

and I'd like to read it:

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 192.168.1.11
search home.
```

I'm not sure where to modify things so I don't screw the current setup.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not have Gnome in english, please apologize if the menu are a bit different.

It seems that you are using NetworkManager to manage your connections.

Look in NetworkManager  configuration: Right click on its icon, "Modify Connections", select "auto eth0" connection -> modify -> IPv4.

Set "DHCP for address only", then put your custom settings there for DNS and search domains there.

Answer (score 1):

The DNS server is being set via dhcp in your configuration.  You'll have to tell Network Manager NOT to use the server suggested by DHCP, but to use a different one instead.  I would try the following in `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
# The primary network interface
auto eth0
    dns-nameservers 1.1.1.1
```

Answer (score 0):

On most linux systems you can just modify /etc/resolv.conf directly. Since yours says it was generated by NetworkManager, perhaps you should look into either setting these options in NetworkManager (by right clicking on the little network connectivity icon on your toolbar) or turning it off and managing the link yourself.

Some distros also have header/footer files that get prepended or appended to the /etc/resolv.conf file that allows you to suppliment whatever data NetworkManager tries to put in there.